# Gridview cell value on RowCommand

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

I'm attempting to get the cell value from a gridview but running into a few issues. I have setup my code similar to this [example](http://interviews.dotnetthread.com/2009/02/making-gridview-rows-or-individual.html) except that I'm adding my button fields on the server side. For some reason RowCommand is firing twice when clicking the cell values? TIA for any help

Page Load is empty:
   `code`

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Adding Button Field:
    `code`

```
   foreach (DataColumn col in transposedTable.Columns)
    {

        ButtonField bfield = new ButtonField();



        bfield.DataTextField = col.ColumnName;

        bfield.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;

        bfield.CommandName = "ColumnClick";

        gvTest.Columns.Add(bfield);

    }
```

The RowDataBound and RowCommand events are the same as the example link above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok...There seems to be an open bug in MSFT connect... 
[GridView RowCommad Event Firing Twice](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/102115/gridview-rowcommand-event-firing-twice)

seems like there are some workarounds posted in the Workarounds tab...

Hope this helps...

Comment: I used session variables to avoid the duplicate postbacks from clearing my variables. A hokey solution but about the only thing that worked. As always, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. I had the same problem.

I removed the Handles `GridView.RowCommand` from the code behind event declaration, and
added this line to the properties declaration for the grid in the `.aspx` source:

```
OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand"
```

Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to access row values in a grid is to use the Cells collection along with the grid's current index (which you can access via the eventargs) as shown below

```
void YOUR_GRID_EVENT(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) 
{
    Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
}
```

you can also make use of the findcontrol as below:

```
var txtName = e.Row.FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
```

Hope this helps...

**Update**

Also check your code to make sure that you are calling the GridView's DataBind() method appropriately...because every time you call GridView.DataBind()...the rowcommand event of the grid view gets called...I think (guessing) you currently have a gridView.DataBind() in your onload as well as in the button click event..so that might cause the rowcommand event to be called twice...if this is not the case then post some code so that we can explore more...

Comment: Thanks.... I understand how to get the data but am curious why is the event being fired twice?

Comment: @BlakeAdams oh that happens if you happen to have the grid.DataBind() code called more than once...so make sure that you are not calling grid.DataBind() method twice in your page flow...debugging is your best friend here...

Comment: Seems that when I click on the value in the cell two RowCommand events are fired, when I select on the cell and not the value it generates one? Seems odd but I'm wondering if it could be related to the button fields?

Comment: @BlakeAdams probably you will need to post some code (i.e. your events code/on load event code)...So that we can take a look at it...